# Is it possible to mention all columns in the "where" clause in AWS S3 Select?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, select, amazon-s3

My input file is stored in S3 bucket. I am using AWS S3 Select to query the data. I am doing this using a python script. It works fine for single columns. But I need to know: if I want to scan the entire file (all columns), can I mention something like below in the query:

```
r = s3.select_object_content(
        Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        Key='Import_data_2019.csv',
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression="Select * from s3object s where s.* = 'Computer'",
        InputSerialization={'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}},
        OutputSerialization={'CSV': {}},
)
```

Basically, I need to find out which columns in the file have the value "Computer".

Comment: You cannot use 's.*' for the where clause.  Are you trying to use 's.*' because you don’t know the names of the columns (perhaps because they’re different from one file to the next)?

Comment: The column names are same. But problem is there are around 1500 columns and i need to check in each and every column